# Why this triangle reordering algorithm results in random connections?

Tags: c++, algorithm, 3d, mesh, indexed

So, I found this index reordering/optimizer algorithm which is supposed to sort the triangles composing an arbitrary 3D mesh in a way that improves spatial locality, hopefully increasing performance in a real-time rendering application.

https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/master/3rdparty/forsyth-too/forsythtriangleorderoptimizer.cpp

I'm running into problems while testing it.

I exported Blender's Suzanne monkey mesh into a ply file and wrote myself a hideous testing program that reads the ply file, extracts the indices data, sorts them with the aforementioned algorithm and composes the reordered ply file, ready to be imported back in Blender to visually check the results... which aren't promising at all:

[image: right is the original mesh, left is the "optimized" one]

A package with source and the test ply file is available here:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/4nckwq8dezndsbo/forsyth.zip

The only modification I applied to the original algorithm was to replace all instances of "uint16" to "uint", as my amigdala concluded that a 16 bit index list was an unnecessary limitation.

I post here the source anyway:

test2.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "forsythtriangleorderoptimizer.h"
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
float coords[3];
float normals[3];
unsigned char color[3];
//char uv[2];
} vert;

typedef unsigned int uint;
//typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned char byte;


int main() {

    FILE *in_ply, *face_dump, *reordered;

    vert buffv2;

    in_ply=fopen("suzanne.ply","r"); // x y z nx ny nz r g b
    face_dump=fopen("suzanne_reordered.txt","w");

    int vertices, faces, gg, line=0, tt, startpos;

    //extract vertices/faces totals.

    line=0;
    while (1) {
        gg=getc(in_ply);
        if (gg=='\n') line++;
        if (line==3) fscanf(in_ply, "element vertex %d", &vertices);
        if (line==13) fscanf(in_ply, "element face %d", &faces);
        if (line==16) break;
    }
    printf("vertices: %d ", vertices);
    printf("faces: %d\n", faces);

    //pass-through loop to reach indices data

    for (tt=0; tt<vertices; tt++) {
        fscanf(in_ply, "%f %f %f %f %f %f %d %d %d\n",
            &buffv2.coords[0], &buffv2.coords[1], &buffv2.coords[2],
            &buffv2.normals[0], &buffv2.normals[1], &buffv2.normals[2],
            &buffv2.color[0], &buffv2.color[1], &buffv2.color[2] );
    }

    startpos = ftell(in_ply);

    uint* indices=(uint*)calloc(faces, 3*sizeof(int));
    uint* newIndexList=(uint*)calloc(faces, 3*sizeof(int));

    for (tt=0; tt<faces; tt++) {
        fscanf(in_ply, "3 %d %d %d\n", &indices[tt], &indices[tt+1], &indices[tt+2]);
    }

    //call the reorder function

    Forsyth::OptimizeFaces(indices, (uint)faces*3, (uint)vertices, newIndexList, (uint)16);

    //dump the reordered indices in a separate file

    for (tt=0; tt<faces; tt++) {
        fprintf(face_dump, "3 %d %d %d\n", newIndexList[tt], newIndexList[tt+1], newIndexList[tt+2]);
    }

    //build new ply file with ordered indices

    reordered=fopen("suzanne_reordered.ply","wb");
    rewind(in_ply);

    while(1) {
        gg=getc(in_ply);
        putc(gg, reordered);
        if (ftell(in_ply)==startpos) break;
    }

    for (tt=0; tt<faces; tt++) {
        fprintf(reordered, "3 %d %d %d\n", newIndexList[tt], newIndexList[tt+1], newIndexList[tt+2]);
    }


    free(indices);
    free(newIndexList);

    fclose(in_ply);
    fclose(face_dump);
    fclose(reordered);

    return 0;
}
```

forsythtriangleorderoptimizer.h:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  This is an implementation of Tom Forsyth's "Linear-Speed Vertex Cache
//  Optimization" algorithm as described here:
//  http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/papers/fast_vert_cache_opt.html
//
//  This code was authored and released into the public domain by
//  Adrian Stone (stone@gameangst.com).
//
//  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT
//  SHALL ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER
//  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR
//  IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

namespace Forsyth
{
    typedef unsigned int uint;
    //typedef unsigned short uint16;
    typedef unsigned char byte;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  OptimizeFaces
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Parameters:
    //      indexList
    //          input index list
    //      indexCount
    //          the number of indices in the list
    //      vertexCount
    //          the largest index value in indexList
    //      newIndexList
    //          a pointer to a preallocated buffer the same size as indexList to
    //          hold the optimized index list
    //      lruCacheSize
    //          the size of the simulated post-transform cache (max:64)
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void OptimizeFaces(const uint* indexList, uint indexCount, uint vertexCount, uint* newIndexList, uint lruCacheSize);

    namespace
    {
        // code for computing vertex score was taken, as much as possible
        // directly from the original publication.
        float ComputeVertexCacheScore(int cachePosition, uint vertexCacheSize)
        {
            const float FindVertexScore_CacheDecayPower = 1.5f;
            const float FindVertexScore_LastTriScore = 0.75f;

            float score = 0.0f;
            if ( cachePosition < 0 )
            {
                // Vertex is not in FIFO cache - no score.
            }
            else
            {
                if ( cachePosition < 3 )
                {
                    // This vertex was used in the last triangle,
                    // so it has a fixed score, whichever of the three
                    // it's in. Otherwise, you can get very different
                    // answers depending on whether you add
                    // the triangle 1,2,3 or 3,1,2 - which is silly.
                    score = FindVertexScore_LastTriScore;
                }
                else
                {
                    assert ( cachePosition < vertexCacheSize );
                    // Points for being high in the cache.
                    const float scaler = 1.0f / ( vertexCacheSize - 3 );
                    score = 1.0f - ( cachePosition - 3 ) * scaler;
                    score = powf ( score, FindVertexScore_CacheDecayPower );
                }
            }

            return score;
        }

        float ComputeVertexValenceScore(uint numActiveFaces)
        {
            const float FindVertexScore_ValenceBoostScale = 2.0f;
            const float FindVertexScore_ValenceBoostPower = 0.5f;

            float score = 0.f;

            // Bonus points for having a low number of tris still to
            // use the vert, so we get rid of lone verts quickly.
            float valenceBoost = powf ( static_cast<float>(numActiveFaces),
                -FindVertexScore_ValenceBoostPower );
            score += FindVertexScore_ValenceBoostScale * valenceBoost;

            return score;
        }


        const uint kMaxVertexCacheSize = 64;
        const uint kMaxPrecomputedVertexValenceScores = 64;
        float s_vertexCacheScores[kMaxVertexCacheSize+1][kMaxVertexCacheSize];
        float s_vertexValenceScores[kMaxPrecomputedVertexValenceScores];

        bool ComputeVertexScores()
        {
            for (uint cacheSize=0; cacheSize<=kMaxVertexCacheSize; ++cacheSize)
            {
                for (uint cachePos=0; cachePos<cacheSize; ++cachePos)
                {
                    s_vertexCacheScores[cacheSize][cachePos] = ComputeVertexCacheScore(cachePos, cacheSize);
                }
            }

            for (uint valence=0; valence<kMaxPrecomputedVertexValenceScores; ++valence)
            {
                s_vertexValenceScores[valence] = ComputeVertexValenceScore(valence);
            }

            return true;
        }
        bool s_vertexScoresComputed = ComputeVertexScores();

        inline float FindVertexCacheScore(uint cachePosition, uint maxSizeVertexCache)
        {
            return s_vertexCacheScores[maxSizeVertexCache][cachePosition];
        }

        inline float FindVertexValenceScore(uint numActiveTris)
        {
            return s_vertexValenceScores[numActiveTris];
        }

        float FindVertexScore(uint numActiveFaces, uint cachePosition, uint vertexCacheSize)
        {
            assert(s_vertexScoresComputed);

            if ( numActiveFaces == 0 )
            {
                // No tri needs this vertex!
                return -1.0f;
            }

            float score = 0.f;
            if (cachePosition < vertexCacheSize)
            {
                score += s_vertexCacheScores[vertexCacheSize][cachePosition];
            }

            if (numActiveFaces < kMaxPrecomputedVertexValenceScores)
            {
                score += s_vertexValenceScores[numActiveFaces];
            }
            else
            {
                score += ComputeVertexValenceScore(numActiveFaces);
            }

            return score;
        }

        struct OptimizeVertexData
        {
            float   score;
            uint    activeFaceListStart;
            uint    activeFaceListSize;
            uint  cachePos0;
            uint  cachePos1;
            OptimizeVertexData() : score(0.f), activeFaceListStart(0), activeFaceListSize(0), cachePos0(0), cachePos1(0) { }
        };
    }

    void OptimizeFaces(const uint* indexList, uint indexCount, uint vertexCount, uint* newIndexList, uint lruCacheSize)
    {
        std::vector<OptimizeVertexData> vertexDataList;
        vertexDataList.resize(vertexCount);

        // compute face count per vertex
        for (uint i=0; i<indexCount; ++i)
        {
            uint index = indexList[i];
            assert(index < vertexCount);
            OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[index];
            vertexData.activeFaceListSize++;
        }

        std::vector<uint> activeFaceList;

        const uint kEvictedCacheIndex = std::numeric_limits<uint>::max();

        {
            // allocate face list per vertex
            uint curActiveFaceListPos = 0;
            for (uint i=0; i<vertexCount; ++i)
            {
                OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[i];
                vertexData.cachePos0 = kEvictedCacheIndex;
                vertexData.cachePos1 = kEvictedCacheIndex;
                vertexData.activeFaceListStart = curActiveFaceListPos;
                curActiveFaceListPos += vertexData.activeFaceListSize;
                vertexData.score = FindVertexScore(vertexData.activeFaceListSize, vertexData.cachePos0, lruCacheSize);
                vertexData.activeFaceListSize = 0;
            }
            activeFaceList.resize(curActiveFaceListPos);
        }

        // fill out face list per vertex
        for (uint i=0; i<indexCount; i+=3)
        {
            for (uint j=0; j<3; ++j)
            {
                uint index = indexList[i+j];
                OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[index];
                activeFaceList[vertexData.activeFaceListStart + vertexData.activeFaceListSize] = i;
                vertexData.activeFaceListSize++;
            }
        }

        std::vector<byte> processedFaceList;
        processedFaceList.resize(indexCount);

        uint vertexCacheBuffer[(kMaxVertexCacheSize+3)*2];
        uint* cache0 = vertexCacheBuffer;
        uint* cache1 = vertexCacheBuffer+(kMaxVertexCacheSize+3);
        uint entriesInCache0 = 0;

        uint bestFace = 0;
        float bestScore = -1.f;

        const float maxValenceScore = FindVertexScore(1, kEvictedCacheIndex, lruCacheSize) * 3.f;

        for (uint i = 0; i < indexCount; i += 3)
        {
            if (bestScore < 0.f)
            {
                // no verts in the cache are used by any unprocessed faces so
                // search all unprocessed faces for a new starting point
                for (uint j = 0; j < indexCount; j += 3)
                {
                    if (processedFaceList[j] == 0)
                    {
                        uint face = j;
                        float faceScore = 0.f;
                        for (uint k=0; k<3; ++k)
                        {
                            uint index = indexList[face+k];
                            OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[index];
                            assert(vertexData.activeFaceListSize > 0);
                            assert(vertexData.cachePos0 >= lruCacheSize);
                            faceScore += vertexData.score;
                        }

                        if (faceScore > bestScore)
                        {
                            bestScore = faceScore;
                            bestFace = face;

                            assert(bestScore <= maxValenceScore);
                            if (bestScore >= maxValenceScore)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                assert(bestScore >= 0.f);
            }

            processedFaceList[bestFace] = 1;
            uint entriesInCache1 = 0;

            // add bestFace to LRU cache and to newIndexList
            for (uint v = 0; v < 3; ++v)
            {
                uint index = indexList[bestFace+v];
                newIndexList[i+v] = index;

                OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[index];

                if (vertexData.cachePos1 >= entriesInCache1)
                {
                    vertexData.cachePos1 = entriesInCache1;
                    cache1[entriesInCache1++] = index;

                    if (vertexData.activeFaceListSize == 1)
                    {
                        --vertexData.activeFaceListSize;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                assert(vertexData.activeFaceListSize > 0);
                uint* begin = &activeFaceList[vertexData.activeFaceListStart];
                uint* end = &activeFaceList[vertexData.activeFaceListStart + vertexData.activeFaceListSize];
                uint* it = std::find(begin, end, bestFace);
                assert(it != end);
                std::swap(*it, *(end-1));
                --vertexData.activeFaceListSize;
                vertexData.score = FindVertexScore(vertexData.activeFaceListSize, vertexData.cachePos1, lruCacheSize);

            }

            // move the rest of the old verts in the cache down and compute their new scores
            for (uint c0 = 0; c0 < entriesInCache0; ++c0)
            {
                uint index = cache0[c0];
                OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[index];

                if (vertexData.cachePos1 >= entriesInCache1)
                {
                    vertexData.cachePos1 = entriesInCache1;
                    cache1[entriesInCache1++] = index;
                    vertexData.score = FindVertexScore(vertexData.activeFaceListSize, vertexData.cachePos1, lruCacheSize);
                }
            }

            // find the best scoring triangle in the current cache (including up to 3 that were just evicted)
            bestScore = -1.f;
            for (uint c1 = 0; c1 < entriesInCache1; ++c1)
            {
                uint index = cache1[c1];
                OptimizeVertexData& vertexData = vertexDataList[index];
                vertexData.cachePos0 = vertexData.cachePos1;
                vertexData.cachePos1 = kEvictedCacheIndex;
                for (uint j=0; j<vertexData.activeFaceListSize; ++j)
                {
                    uint face = activeFaceList[vertexData.activeFaceListStart+j];
                    float faceScore = 0.f;
                    for (uint v=0; v<3; v++)
                    {
                        uint faceIndex = indexList[face+v];
                        OptimizeVertexData& faceVertexData = vertexDataList[faceIndex];
                        faceScore += faceVertexData.score;
                    }
                    if (faceScore > bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = faceScore;
                        bestFace = face;
                    }
                }
            }

            std::swap(cache0, cache1);
            entriesInCache0 = std::min(entriesInCache1, lruCacheSize);
        }
    }

} // namespace Forsyth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aren't you overwriting indices here?

```
for (tt=0; tt<faces; tt++) {
    fscanf(in_ply, "3 %d %d %d\n", &indices[tt], &indices[tt+1], &indices[tt+2]);
}
```

For tt==0 you will get indicies 0, 1, 2. For tt==1 you will write indices 1,2,3 which I think should be 3,4,5 (tt*3, tt*3+1, tt*3+2)

Comment: So, can we just pretend that this question never really existed? Thanks for the answer.